# Create multiple forms from one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make slightly different forms from one model. I am doing administrator part of the site where admins can create different vehicles. Customer requests that site needs to have separate links for creation of different cars.

This would be simplified model:

```
create_table "cars", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "model"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.string   "car_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Site would have something like this:

```
Create new Mercedes
Create new Seat
Create new Alfa Romeo
Create new Peugeot
etc
```

So, `car_type` inside table could contain Mercedes, Seat, Alfa Romeo, Peugeot, etc. When admin clicks on some link, new page opens where he can create that type of car. For example, if he clicks on `Create new Seat`, new site with Seat logo and some random pictures of Seat cars on the left/right side of page.

Depending which link is clicked, the car type would be set automatically like this:

```
<%= form_for @car do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden :car_type, "Seat" %>
<% end %>
```

My question is how can I know which link is clicked so I can generate that field dynamically depending on which car will be created? So, something like this:

```
<%= form_for @car do |f| %>
   <% if ????? Seat %>
     <%= f.hidden :car_type, "Seat" %>
   <% elsif ????? Mercedes %>
     <%= f.hidden :car_type, "Mercedes" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The same way I would generate different manufacturer logo and other things on that page depending on which link is selected. The form for each car is the same.

Thank you for suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

For your car controller you have defined the routes. This gives you some path helper like `new_car_path`. If you use this to create links like

```
new_car_path(car_type: "seat")
```

then in your controller you can get this additional param with `params[:car_type]`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that you can take is to provide a select_box for 'Car_type' and use JS to listen to 'onchange' event.

So, when you select 'Seat' as car type, then the page sends in a request to your controller and then populate the page from the response data.

In short:

1. Select box for 'Car_Type'
2. On selecting a car type, page sends an AJAX request to controller
3. Controller sends relevant data (JSON or whatever)
4. Populate the page with controller response.

I hope I am clear, if not I can provide further information on how to use this approach :)